# How to convert datetime interval to hours?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet:

```
   A            B        C       D          E
1  08/13/2013   02:10    4                  
2  08/13/2013   02:19    10      00:09:00   160
```

In **D2**, I have this formula : `=if(B2="";"";to_date(concatenate(A2;" ";B2))-to_date(concatenate(A1;" ";B1)))`

In **E2** I have this formula : `=if(D2="";"";(C2-C1)/D2)`

But **E2** outputs the wrong result, 160. I want it to be 40 (=(10-4)/0.15). `0.15` is the value in **D2** converted to hours.

How can I do that?

Comment: What does column C exactly do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution thanks to indication from @mhoran_psprep

`=if(D2="";"";(C2-C1)/(D2*24))`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the following formula to calculate the date/time difference in `D2`:

```
=(A2-A1)+(B2-B1)
```

This eliminates floating point errors as you can see in the example file I created: **[DATEDIFF](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEpXU1RlRVAyeFQwVm9tT1loOTJ4aUE&usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 2):

Google as well as Excel treat all times as decimal days.

Therefore 9 minutes is not 0.15 instead it is 9 minutes divided by the number of minutes in a day. or 9/1440 or 0.00625.

Answer (score 1):

You say you

> "want it to be 40 (=(10-4)/0.15)"

Seems to me that you need to add (c2-c1) into your formula, as well as worrying about the time difference.

Comment: I have updated my post...